# Is applying a negative text-indent to an element intended to be an icon still considered good practice today?

Tags: css

A common practice to create icons is to apply a CSS background image and a negative `text-indent`:

```
<a class="facebook" href="#">Facebook</a>

.facebook {
    display: block;
    background: url(images/facebook_icon.svg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Is this still considered good practice though or is there something better accepted today?

Comment: if it works, it's not stupid.

Comment: This may not be a good question for the StackOverflow format - it's too dependent on opinion

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-image-replacement-museum/

Comment: The question is why you want to do that ? Long time ago was the discussion about the negative indent and SEO ...

Answer (score 1):

A much better way would be to utilize Font Awesome icons (or follow the same scheme they do)

http://fontawesome.io/

For example,

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro" title="Take a picture"></i>
```

http://fontawesome.io/examples/

would produce a camera icon. If you then include FA's js plugin

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/XXXXX.js"></script>
```

http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

FA will automatically (depending on the options you pick) make the icon screen-reader friendly (without using text-indent) and supply you with pre-made icons that you don't need to host yourself, reducing clutter. They even have an option to load the icons after everything else, meaning it won't impact load times on your site.